# Kohana 3.2, ORM has_many, belongs_to relationship not referencing the correct key

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I have two tables named `utilities` and `types` that i am trying to access the other fields within types from the utilities view. e.g; `$utilities->type->type;`

Utilities would `have_one` type
and type would `belong_to` utility right?

This is how i have it currently, and rather than referencing `utilities.type_id` its setting the key as `utilities.id`. As a result its pulling different types for each row, even though they are all of the same type.

[image]

How should i lay my models relationships out using Kohana 3.2 ORM.

### Utilities

```
<?php
class Model_Utility extends ORM {
    protected $_has_one = array(
        'type' => array(
            'model' => 'type',
            'foreign_key' => 'type_id',
        ),
    );
```

#### Table Structure

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| utility_name  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| type_id       | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| contact_name  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| contact_email | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| contact_phone | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### Types

```
class Model_Type extends ORM {
    protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'utility' => array(
        )
    );
```

#### Table Structure

```
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| type_id | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| type    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: im surprised this hasnt been answered..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utility `belongs_to` Type (`utilities` has a `type_id` key), and Type `has_many` utilities.

PS. Also you need to define a PK name for `types` table (`$_primary_key` property).

Comment: thanks for the answer, i was missing the `$_primary_key` property.